# Is it safe to call a non-void function inside kernel without assigning to variable

Tags: c, linux-kernel, spinlock

I am *trying* to debug a kernel code, because of a "scheduling while in atomic" that is crashing my system. In some point of an actual kernel module I added a line for calling a function defined in another kernel module (this one made by me). The call is:

```
mycallback(svc, skb);
```

And `mycallback()` function returns `int`. So I have 2 questions:

1. Is it safe to call a non-void function inside the kernel without asigning its result to a variable?
2. If the code where `mycallback()` is called would be spin_locked or something like that, would it be safe? Would it be spin_locked/atomic or I might sleep and compromise the kernel?

Comment: Ignoring a return value doesn't change the calling convention .. however, it might be an important value. In any case, please focus on *one* question at a time. (Question #2 seems [more] interesting.)

Comment: @pst Thanks, I was almost completely sure about Question #1. I am concerned on Question #2, any help with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it safe to call a non-void function inside the kernel without
>   asigning its result to a variable?

Yes.

> If the code where `mycallback()` is called would be spin_locked or
>   something like that, would it be safe? Would it be spin_locked/atomic
>   or I might sleep and compromise the kernel?

If the code that calls `mycallback()` can hold a spinlock, `mycallback()` **must not** call any functions that can sleep.  If you do try to sleep while holding a spinlock, you will see the "Scheduling while atomic" crash that you've described.

Potentially sleeping functions include `copy_to_user()`, `copy_from_user()`, `kmalloc()` (without the `GFP_ATOMIC` flag), `mutex_lock()` and a lot more beside.

Comment: Thank you very much, this helps me a lot to clarify ideas. How could I know what functions/sentences may sleep? By example, in `mycallback()` I am calling another functions that also returns `int`, within this other function I have a `while` loop, a `list_for_each_entry` and some `strcpy()`... Could it be that any of them may sleep?

Comment: Most low-level functions that can sleep have a call to `might_sleep()` or `might_fault()` in them.  None of the things you've described sleeps.

Comment: The scheduling while atomic warning should give you a backtrace, which will show you where you've called a sleeping function.